# Print is invalid Syntax? [Python 3]

Tags: python, math, syntax

I'm trying to write a program that will do some simple math for a video game, however I am encountering multiple errors.

the string after Print IS in brackets, because of Python 3.
I also get "Calculation error" if I try to enter 1.5 or a value similar for 'FCS'

```
import decimal
print("ARMORED CORE V - FCS SIMULATION")
print("This program will calculate lock times for weapons combined with their FCS in           Armored Core V")
print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------")

#Base Weapon Lock/FCS Lock Percentage (150=1.5)/60
#Seidenbaum at 421 Base Lock
#421/1.5/60 is lock time (4.67 seconds)
#Subcomputer: Base Weapon Lock/FCS Lock Percentage/Subcomp Lock Percentage  (320=3.02)/Second Subcomp/60
#Subcomps: 421/1.5/3.02/60 (1.54 Seconds)
#Dual Subcomps: 421/1.5/3.02/3.02/60 (0.5 Seconds)

while (1 == 1):
    command = input("\nTo begin, type 'compute'\nThen enter your weapon's Base Lock Time\nThen your FCS' Lock Computation\nAnd then how many Subcomputers you have\nyou can also type help [ compute // help ]")
    if command == "help":
        print("\nFollow the instuctions as prompted\n\nI will also display the Lock Times and Subcomp Acceleration for FCSes and Subcomputers")
        print("--FCSes--\nUFC-11 GLANCE - 1.7 Lock Computation\nFCS-09 YASAKANI - 1.05 Lock Computation\nKV-1T2/OTKRYT - 0.75 Lock Computation\nFCS-07/Lr UZUME - 1.8 Lock Computation\nSEHER FCS199 - 1 Lock Computation\nPREDIRE FCS190 - 1.5 Lock Computation\n--SUBCOMPUTERS--\nSUBCOMPUTER USC-1 DHANBAD - 3.02 Lock Improvment\nSUBCOMPUTER SBC-9 TSUKUYOMI - 3.06 Missile Lock Improvement [Enter Normally]")
    if command == "compute":
        baselock = input("\n\nEnter your weapon's Base Lock Time >> ")
        fcs = input("\nEnter your FCS' Lock Computation as a Percentage >> ")
        subcompone = input("\nEnter your first Subcomputer's lock improvment\n Enter '1' if you don't have any subcomps >> ")
        subcomptwo = input("\nEnter your second Subcomputer's lock improvment\n Enter '1' if you don't have a second subcomputer >> ")
        try: 
locktime = float(int(baselock)//int(decimal.decimal(fcs)//int(decimal.decimal(subcompone)//int(decimal.decimal(subcomptwo)//60)
                return(locktime)
                print("Seconds")
        except ValueError:
            print("error in calculation")
```

Comment: We have no clue what the traceback looks like. And neither do you, by the looks of it.

Comment: Crazily, Google finds an old version of your code [here](http://ideone.com/Y8Cqvn) (I was curious which video game you were referring to).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a closing parantheses on the line

```
locktime = float(int(baselock)//int(decimal.decimal('fcs')//int(subcompone)//int(subcomptwo)//60))
```

Also, I'm assuming this is in the function and that `return` is needed, but `print('seconds')` won't be executed if the return is hit. **It is unreachable.**

Comment: Yep. I said it in the last statement. Should make it more profound. Thanks. :)